# How can I add multiple rules in a GetLegendGraphic request in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, sld, getlegendgraphic

I am using following GetLegendGraphcs request

[https://develop.blaa.nl/data/test/wms?LAYER=nccw:variabele_woz&request=GetLegendGraphic&format=image/png&styles=nccw_variabele_woz&rule=one](https://develop.blaa.nl/data/test/wms?LAYER=nccw%3avariabele_woz&request=GetLegendGraphic&format=image/png&styles=nccw_variabele_woz&rule=one)

With this I am able to get Legend for Phase 1. I have rules for Phase 2 (rule2) , Phase 3 (rule3) and phase 4 (rule4) too. If I want rules for Phase 1 and Phase 2, how shall I use GetLegendGraphics request where I can include more rules.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: What if you apply multiple styles in your request each with their own rule set; like: `https://develop.blaa.nl/data/test/wms?LAYER=nccw%3avariabele_woz&request=GetLegendGraphic&format=image/png&style=nccw_variabele_woz,some-otherstyle&`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **RULES** instead of RULE in your url to pass multiple rules

https://develop.blaa.nl/data/test/wms?LAYER=nccw:variabele_woz&request=GetLegendGraphic&format=image/png&styles=nccw_variabele_woz&rules=one,two,three

Comment: This does not seems to work.
Can you provide a link to documentation on it / a working example?

Comment: This is working in our geoserver